# NodeJS request.get body

Tags: node.js

I want to use NodeJS to get the response from 2 urls, and put them in an array for later processing.

I am unable to store the body/resp outside the request.get function. Resp has `undefined` outside request.get.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong? Thx

```
var msurls = ["http://example.org/get1", "http://example.org/get2"];
var request = require("request");
var msresult = [];

msurls.forEach(function(msurl) {
        var resp;
        request.get(msurl,function(error,response,body){
                if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                } else {
                        resp = body;
                }
        });
        msresult.push(resp);
});
console.log(msresult);
```

Comment: you should learn about asynchronous programing. your code is synchronous as well.

Comment: As Kai said, learn about async/await keywords https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the timing of your code. Your `msresult.push(resp);` is fired before you `request.get` has finished, so you are pushing `resp` that doesn't have a value yet.

I **think** you can use await as so... (I may be wrong though)

```
var msurls = ["http://example.org/get1", "http://example.org/get2"];
var request = require("request");
var msresult = [];

msurls.forEach(function(msurl) {
    await request.get(msurl, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            msresult.push(body);
        }
    });
});
console.log(msresult);
```

Comment: You're using `await` with a callback which is wrong, if you use a callback, request is not going to return a `Promise`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) - it allows you to execute multiple async requests.

Cleaner solution would be:

```
const request = require("request");

const getData = async (requests) => {
  return Promise.all(requests);
};

const doWork = async () => {
  const msurls = ["http://example.org/get1", "http://example.org/get2"];
  const requests = msurls.map(url => request.get(url));

  const result = await getData(requests);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
};
```

As for further learning, take a look into ES6 features Node supports and read up about asynchronous programming in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`request` module doesn't support promises, use `request-promise-native` instead, if not, you have to use callbacks as @Gediminas wrote.

I do prefer this even cleaner solution which is more modern javascript:

```
let msurls = ["http://example.org", "http://example.org"]
let request = require("request-promise-native")

async function doRequests() {
    return await(Promise.all(
        msurls.map(async msurl => await request(msurl)))
    )
}

doRequests().then(msresult => console.log(msresult))
```

You already have an array with the results and the code looks synchronous.